# clicking submit button on aspx page programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, web-scraping

I have a list of Ids whose information available through a webpage. I need to input the Id and click the submit button for that. The numbers of ids runs over a million, so I need to automate this process. Is it possible to use Web scraping. I don't know where to start this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture a single request you do manually and use this as your template. Then you'll have to add some code to manage the session and other cookies.